# Is it possible for a thread to just die without throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a situation on a production machine where a thread in my Windows Service appears simply to die, without throwing an exception.  To date my logging hasn't been verbose enough to pinpoint the exact line of code where it is dying; I've deployed a new version with more verbose logging for this purpose.  But until I get a smoking gun, my suspicion falls on the line of code where I create a new DB context.

The error is not predictable, except that it tends to happen during periods of high activity, and is often correlated with other threads throwing DB timeout exceptions (hence my suspicion above).  Exceptions I can handle.  Dead threads I can't.

Any ideas why a thread might die silently, or otherwise simply freeze?  Or what to do about it?

**EDIT:** To be clear, the code is surrounded by a try-catch block, and the catch does some logging (using log4net).  So does the "finally".  I know it's working because other threads have left logs when they threw exceptions.  All that I see in my log is that thread *x* hits a certain debug point, then is never seen or heard from again, and the work it was supposed to do remains not done.

Comment: What do you mean "die"? Are you sure it finishes execution? Might very well be a deadlock.

Comment: what is the timeout set at for said DB context..? can you show an snippet of the actual code..? perhaps you're exception handling could be drilled down a bit further.. hard to really determine without seeing any existing code

Comment: Since threads can’t just *disappear* but need to be actually terminated by the operating system, I don’t think that this can be done without an exception being thrown.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't throw an exception? Do you have a try/catch block around all the code in the thread?

Comment: Could it be hanging?

Comment: @LeandroTaset Wouldn't a deadlock throw an exception?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Define "hanging"?

Comment: Stopping, waiting for something, endless loop, ie. not going forward, but haven't crashed either.

Comment: i don't think a dealock would throw an exception it will just be there waiting on both sides, or unless memory runs out.

Comment: Not a dead thread issue, but something similar. If you have a `System.Timers.Timer` and the event handler throws an exception, you won't ever see it, unless you wrap your handler in a try/catch and log the exception. The result is that it will look like your timer isn't firing.

Comment: @ShaulBehr: Nope, there would be no exception thrown by the CLR. [Wikipedia - Deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

Comment: @StevenHernandez: "memory runs out" - That sounds more like a [livelock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Livelock).

Comment: @LeandroTaset thanks for the insight, I stand corrected. It would be a livelock. Still I believe it wouldn't call an exception because technically nothing crashed, yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the system i would debug it with: **Visual Studio 2013 Remote Debugger**. This is often a good choice if you can't reproduce the error in your development environment.

Threads do not silently freeze or crash, check whether you have some empty `catch` blocks in your code or it runs into an infinite loop (or very long timeout at any point).

Maybe you have some code for us.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really (but kind of).  Threads don't die, they finish.  A thread can finish successfully or by failure--if a thread fails then its exception is stored until it is handled.  Depending on how you instantiate the thread it's possible that you "fire and forget", meaning that if an exception occurs you have no code to handle and retrieve it.  This is doubly bad, as it results in unreleased resources (they're waiting for you to retrieve and handle the exception).

However, you haven't provided any details of what you've diagnosed.  What threading approach/framework are you using (there's quite a few)? Are you watching the processes threads and seeing it suddenly disappear?  Are you taking heap snapshots, or attaching to the running process after it appears to have died?